# R ggplot2 - issue with errorbar width

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, width, errorbar

I've been trying to plot the following data using ggplot2, but I ran into an issue with the errorbars:

```
data1<-c(0.04, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 ,2.0, 2.6, 3.1, 3.6,  0.9,0.56,0.4,0.33,0.27,0.2,0.15,0.1, 0.12, 0.17, 0.22 ,0.33, 0.45,  0.57, 0.74, 0.85)

sym<-as.data.frame(matrix(data = data1, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE))

ggplot(data=sym, mapping = aes(x=sym[,1], y=sym[,2]))+
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="black",linetype = 1),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size =30),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color="black"),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=25, margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")))+
  ggtitle("variable, symmetric error")+
  ylim(-1.0, 1.5)+
  xlim(0.0,4.5)+
  geom_line(color="blue",size=1.2)+
  geom_point(color="blue", size=4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = sym[,2]-sym[,3], ymax = sym[,2]+sym[,3], x= sym[,1]),
                width=0.1, color="blue", size =1.2)
```

The result is (mainly) as expected, but I cannot figure out why the first errorbar is not responding to the "width" setting. [Plot showing the issue with the first errorbar, which is not responding to the set width parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43cvW.png)

My first guess was that changing the margin may have caused some sort of overlapping, which led R to not plot width-wise for the very first point. However, shifting the data inwards on the x-axis made no difference. Therefore I'm assuming I must have missed something else?

Any input is very much appreciated!

Comment: The reason is that that you have set the lower limit of the x-axis to zero. Try `xlim(-0.1, 4.5)`

Comment: ... and if you want to increase the width you have adjust the limit accordingly

Comment: @stefan Or remove the call to `xlim` alltogether. Also, in `ggplot2` graphics don't use `sym[,1]`, etc, use the column names, `V1`, etc.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your prompt reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing to the great suggestions of @stefan and @RuiBarradas about the variable names and limits, you can also try `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous()` for limits as it is used in next code:

```
ggplot(data=sym, mapping = aes(x=V1, y=V2))+
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color="black",linetype = 1),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size =30),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color="black"),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.25, "cm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=25, margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm")))+
  ggtitle("variable, symmetric error")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(NA,1.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(NA,4.5))+
  geom_line(color="blue",size=1.2)+
  geom_point(color="blue", size=4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = V2-V3, ymax = V2+V3, x= V1),
                width=0.1, color="blue", size =1.2)
```

[image]